# Variable null in class

Tags: php, dependencies

here is my code:

```
// Use the REST API Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = '***';
$token = '***';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

class TextMessage {

    function sendTextMessage() {

        $client->messages->create(
            '+10000000000',
            array(
                'from' => '+1123456790',
                'body' => 'Hello, this is just a test text message'
                )
            );

    }

}
```

I get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in

how can i fix this problem WITHOUT using global? thanks!

Comment: add `global $client;` in `sendTextMessage` function.

Comment: @SahilGulati sorry i don't want to use global

Comment: Do as the other comment (that was delete now--->now an answer) was saying, inject `$client` into `sendtTextMessage()` or `__construct()` as noted in their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$client` is null because it's undefined in the scope of your `sendTextMessage` method.

Add a constructor method to your class and inject the client. Then use `$this->client` instead of `$client`.

```
class TextMessage {

    function __construct($client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    function sendTextMessage() {

        $this->client->messages->create(
            '+10000000000',
            array(
                'from' => '+1123456790',
                'body' => 'Hello, this is just a test text message'
                )
            );

    }

}

$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$textMessage = new TextMessage($client);
```

---

OR

Pass the client as an argument to the `sentTextMessage` method.

```
class TextMessage {

    function sendTextMessage($client) {

        $client->messages->create(
            '+10000000000',
            array(
                'from' => '+1123456790',
                'body' => 'Hello, this is just a test text message'
                )
            );

    }

}

$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$textMessage = new TextMessage;
$textMessage->setTextMessage($client);
```